# jQuery clone in React is not passing click listeners to the clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, onclick

I am building a table with fixed columns and my approach is to clone the table and place it on top position absolute, only showing the columns that are fixed.

I am using jQuery to clone, add class, and appending it to my DOM.

My table headers have a button and with cloning, I want the click listener to work on the clone.

Here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dv0vumm/) for an example of the problem.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    jQuery('.button').clone(true).appendTo('#container')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <button 
          className="button" 
          onClick={() => alert('hi')}
         >
          say hi
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Any ideas/solutions would be extremely helpful. If I can't go this route, I think I will have to create the same table again with a class for styling.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding jQuery to a React project is not a good idea. jQuery is a direct DOM manipulator while React works from a Virtual DOM to intelligently update the DOM when necessary.

If you need to clone and you are using react, it's best to find a react way of doing it.

This should essentially do the same thing without jQuery ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dv0vumm/1/)):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        clone: ['first clone']
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ clone: [...this.state.clone, 'new clone'] })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        { this.state.clone.map((v, i) => 
          <button
            key={i}
            className="button" 
            onClick={() => alert('hi')}
          >
            say hi
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: What if you still needed to use jquery for 'reasons'?